# Bluepay Security Error

Tags: php

I am trying to implement bluepay payment service in my PHP project,but I'm getting a return message of "Security Error". Here's the exact debug page results:
Response: STATUS=E&MESSAGE=SECURITY%20ERROR
Trans Id:
Status: E
AVS Resp:
CVV2 Resp:
Auth Code:
Message: SECURITY ERROR
Rebid:

I'm using the correct merchant ID and Secret Key.

Does anyone has any idea!!!! Please help me!

Answer (score 2):

There are only 2 ways to get a security error in the BluePay gateway.  1). wrong account ID  2). wrong tamper proof seal, which is usually the result of the wrong secret key.  We always suggest people to copy and past those 2 items and assuming you have it in there correctly, please call or email me directly and I'll be more than happy to look at your exact account and see what the error shows up as on our logs.  Thanks.

Tim Trench
184 Shuman Blvd # 350
Naperville, IL 60563
P: 630-300-2418
F: 866-422-6011
E: ttrench@bluepay.com
www.bluepay.com

Comment: Thanks for your reply!!
I am sure , i am using the correct Account ID and secret key. Before posting the data to bluepay, the tamper proof seal variable contains the following data


i am contactinating all the variable to another variable named as ($tamper_proof_data)

as shown below

 $tamper_proof_data = $this->_postData['SECRET_KEY'] . $this->_postData['ACCOUNT_ID'] .$this->_postData['TRANS_TYPE'] . $this->_postData['AMOUNT'] .$this->_postData['MASTER_ID'].$this->_postData['NAME1'].$this->_postData['PAYMENT_ACCOUNT']; 
$this->_postData['TAMPER_PROOF_SEAL']=bin2hex(md5($tamper_proof_data));

Comment: my doubt is,  is this is the variable you said as tamper proof seal?????.
if not please make more clear about this and what is the exact method to do it.